# H-polar decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can anyone help me understand how this paper: http://www.cs.vu.nl/~ran/polarnormal.pdf

figured out $(14)$ from Example **12** (on page **14**)?

The problem is essentially asking for a polar decomposition of

$X=\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & r & z \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$

**where $r>0$ and $z=\pm 1$**.

However, I do not understand where the $H$ matrix is coming from, and how they came up with it! Same goes for $U$ and $A$ matrices.

And yes, I read the paper, but I *still* don't understand!

Comment: They say in the paper that this example is taken from reference [14], which is 

`C. V. M. van der Mee, A. C. M. Ran, and L. Rodman. Stability of self-adjoint square roots and polar decompositions in indefinite scalar product spaces. Linear Algebra
Appl., 302-303:77-104, 1999.`

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Hi there. I looked through that paper as well, but I still don't get it. It turns out that my approach yesterday was wrong.

Comment: Hi there yourself. The most I understand from the example is that $X$ and $H$ are examples to demonstrate theorem 10.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It seems like the handout only concerns itself with existence and not construction. The examples are just demonstrating this.